# How do you restore the state between pages?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have an app which gives me a score at the end of the game and I want the users to share their scores on facebook.

I want scoring information to be restored to the "end game" screen after the user has logged into facebook, and move to the facebook section of the panorama/pivot.

How do I go about this? Do I save that information to storage or to I use a variable in app.xaml.cs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store this data in the page's `State` property in the `OnNavigatingFrom` or `OnNavigatedFrom` events of the page.
You can then access it again in the `OnNavigatedTo` event.

The situation you are handling is called tombstoning. Read more about it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: thanks, i was thinking tombstoning was for exiting the app only.